# Creating a slideshow but getting error Uncaught ReferenceError: currentYearSlide is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a slideshow work with the code below. It should be a list of years above a div with a h4 and a p floating to the left, and a picture floating to the right. I keep getting the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: currentYearSlide is not defined but i don't know why as it should be. I'm probably overlooking something really simple.

All of these should match to the slide with the correct information when either the user clicks the year or moves onto the next slide using the arrows.

I also want two sets of arrows, one by the years and one by the pictures which do the same thing, but that should be easy as it should be the same JavaScript code.

```js
var yearSlideIndex = 1;
  showYearSlides(yearSlideIndex);

  window.plusYearSlides = function (n) {
    showYearSlides(yearSlideIndex += n);
  };

  window.currentYearSlide = function (n) {
    showYearSlides(yearSlideIndex = n);
  };

  function showYearSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var yearSlides = document.getElementsByClassName("myYearSlides");
    var yearDots = document.getElementsByIDName("dotYear");
    if (n > yearSlides.length) {yearSlideIndex = 1;}    
    if (n < 1) {yearSlideIndex = yearSlides.length;}
    for (i = 0; i < yearSlides.length; i++) {
     yearSlides[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    for (i = 0; i < yearDots.length; i++) {
     yearDots[i].className = yearDots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    yearSlides[yearSlideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    yearDots[yearSlideIndex-1].className += " active";
  }
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0}
.mySlides {display: none}
.myYearSlides {display: none}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
 max-width: 130em;
 position: relative;
 margin: auto;
 width: 100%;
 &.year {
  position: relative;
  max-width: none;
 }
 img {
  @include curvededges();
  width: 130em;
     object-fit: cover;
     margin-top: 0.5em;
     max-height: 79em;
  margin: 0em;
  @include respond($massive-width, $half-four-k){
   max-height: 58.5em;
  }
  @include respond($laptop, $massive-width){
   max-height: 56.5em;
  }
  @include respond($desktop, $laptop) {
   max-height: 42em;
  }
  @include respond($tablet, $desktop) {
   max-height: 29.5em;
  }
  @include respond($tablet) {
   max-height: 21.75em;
  }
  @include respond($large-mobile) {
   max-height: 15.5em;
  }
  @include respond($mobile) {
   max-height: 13.75em;
  }
  @include respond($small-mobile) {
   max-height: 11.25em;
  }
 }
}
.mySlides {
 margin-top: 0.35em;
}
/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}
.open_arrow {
 cursor: pointer;
 color: $white;
 border-radius: 50%;
}
/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev, .next {
 display: none;
 &.year{
  display: inline;
 }
}
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  display: none;
}
.year_nav {
 text-align:center;
 margin-top: 2em;
}
/* Caption text */
.text {
 font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif; 
    color: $white;
 font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 8em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1em;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
 &.year {
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 1em;
    padding: 1.5em 0.5em;
    position: relative;
 width: 50%;
    text-align: left;
 }
 @include respond($laptop, $massive-width){
  font-size: 4em;
 }
 @include respond($laptop){
  font-size: 3em;
 }
 @include respond($tablet){
  font-size: 2em;
 }
 @include respond($mobile-nav){
  font-size: 1.25em;
 }
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 3em;
    width: 3em;
    margin: 0 1em;
    background-color: transparent;
 border: solid $white 2px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
 &.year {
  border: none;
     margin: 0em 1.75em;
     font-size: 1.5em;
  span {
   opacity: 0.5;
   font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif; 
  }
 }
 @include respond ($laptop) {
  height: 1.5em;
  width: 1.5em;
 margin: 0em 0.5em;
 }
 @include respond ($tablet) {
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  margin: 0em;
 }
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: $white;
 &.year{
  background-color: transparent;
  span {
   opacity: 1;
  }
 }
}

.dot_box {
 position: absolute;
    top: 82em;
    left: 52em;
    text-align: center;
 @include respond($massive-width, $half-four-k){
  top: 63.5em;
     left: 32em;
 }
 @include respond($laptop, $massive-width) {
  top: 62.5em;
     left: 32em;
 }
 @include respond($desktop, $laptop) {
  top: 47em;
     left: 26.5em;
 }
 @include respond($tablet, $desktop) {
  top: 36em;
     left: 16.5em;
 }
 @include respond($tablet) {
  top: 29em;
     left: 14.5em;
 }
 @include respond($large-mobile) {
  top: 20em;
  left: 9.5em;
 }
 @include respond($mobile) {
  top: 18.5em;
     left: 8em;
 }
 @include respond($small-mobile) {
  top: 16em;
     left: 6em;
 }
}
/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}
.year_nav{
 background-color: transparent;
 color: $white;
 font-weight: 600;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
}
```

```html
<section class="main__section pink">
    <div class="content__centre pink">
     <div class="slideshow-container">
      <!-- The dots/circles -->
      <div class="year_nav">
       <a class="prev year" onclick="plusYearSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
       <span id="dotYear" class="dot year" onclick="currentYearSlide(1)">1990</span> 
       <span id="dotYear" class="dot year" onclick="currentYearSlide(2)">1993</span> 
       <span id="dotYear" class="dot year" onclick="currentYearSlide(3)">1995</span>
       <span id="dotYear" class="dot year" onclick="currentYearSlide(4)">1998</span>
       <span id="dotYear" class="dot year" onclick="currentYearSlide(5)">2001</span>
       <span id="dotYear" class="dot year" onclick="currentYearSlide(6)">2002</span>
       <span id="dotYear" class="dot year" onclick="currentYearSlide(7)">2003</span>
       <span id="dotYear" class="dot year" onclick="currentYearSlide(8)">2005</span>
       <span id="dotYear" class="dot year" onclick="currentYearSlide(9)">2006</span>
       <span id="dotYear" class="dot year" onclick="currentYearSlide(10)">2008</span>
       <span id="dotYear" class="dot year" onclick="currentYearSlide(11)">2010</span>
       <span id="dotYear" class="dot year" onclick="currentYearSlide(12)">2012</span>
       <a class="next year" onclick="plusYearSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
      </div>
       <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
        <div class="myYearSlides fade">
       <div class="numbertext">1 / 12</div>
       <h4>1990</h4>
       <div class="text year">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br /><br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
        </div>

        <div class="myYearSlides fade">
       <div class="numbertext">2 / 12</div>
       <h4>1993</h4>
       <div class="text year">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br /><br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
        </div>
      <div class="myYearSlides fade">
       <div class="numbertext">3 / 12</div>
       <h4>1995</h4>
       <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br /><br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
        </div>
      <div class="myYearSlides fade">
       <div class="numbertext">4 / 12</div>
       <h4>1998</h4>
       <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br /><br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
        </div>
      <div class="myYearSlides fade">
       <div class="numbertext">5 / 12</div>
       <h4>2001</h4>
       <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br /><br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
        </div>
      <div class="myYearSlides fade">
       <div class="numbertext">6 / 12</div>
       <h4>2002</h4>
       <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br /><br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
        </div>
      <div class="myYearSlides fade">
       <div class="numbertext">7 / 12</div>
       <h4>2003</h4>
       <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br /><br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
        </div>
      <div class="myYearSlides fade">
       <div class="numbertext">8 / 12</div>
       <h4>2005</h4>
       <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br /><br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
        </div>
      
      <div class="myYearSlides fade">
       <div class="numbertext">9 / 12</div>
       <h4>2006</h4>
       <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br /><br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
        </div>
      
      <div class="myYearSlides fade">
       <div class="numbertext">10 / 12</div>
       <h4>2008</h4>
       <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br /><br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum..</div>
        </div>
      
      <div class="myYearSlides fade">
       <div class="numbertext">11 / 12</div>
       <h4>2010</h4>
       <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br /><br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
        </div>
      
      <div class="myYearSlides fade">
       <div class="numbertext">12 / 12</div>
       <h4>2012</h4>
       <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br /><br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: An ID must be unique in a document. getElementsByIDName does not exist.

Comment: `var yearDots = document.getElementsByIDName("dotYear");` syntax is wrong. Cange to `document.getElementById(id)` and ID must be Unique

Comment: I've changed that but it still wont show any of the slides I've created. It doesn't make any sense as it works for another slideshow I made earlier. Thank you for your help btw!